# How to retrieve access token from ClaimsTransformationContext

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 to secure an mvc app and all peripheral APIs. During principal creation I'm using the claims transformation middleware, in which I'd like to make a call to a secured API for additional information.

The claims transformation middleware is wired up in the `Configure` method like so:

```
 app.UseClaimsTransformation(o => new ClaimsTransformer().TransformAsync(o));
```

And the `ClaimsTransformer` class looks like:

```
   public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext    context)
   {
       // meat and potatoes goes here...
       return context.Principal;
   }
```

I've tried getting the access token from the `ClaimsTransformationContext` with the following code within `TransformAsync`, however this seems to result in an infinite loop back to the `TransformAsync` method on the `ClaimsTransformer` class.

```
 var accessToken = context.Context.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

Is it possible to retrieve the access token during the .net core claims transformation?

Or is this specific API call something htat shouldn't be done on behalf of the user and better handled one step up and suited for a more server to server approach (client credentials grant)?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I have hit exactly the same issue. I thought I was doing the right thing trying to inject business claims into the user principle through claims transformation - also calling an API and need the access token in the TransformAsync method. Perhaps this is just not the way to do it, given the lack of information I can find.

Comment: No I came to the conclusion what I was trying to do either wasn't possible or shouldn't be done. Rather than trying to use the access token (which I was never able to retrieve in this context properly), I used the client credentials grant to communicate with the secured API at the app level rather than the user level.